# How can I create link template in Yii2 bootstrap Nav widget

Tags: php, yii2, widget

How can I create link template in Yii2 bootstrap Nav widget?

```
echo \yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class'=>'top_choice'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Finish',  'options' => ['class' => 'tab'], 'url' => ['/finish'], 'template' => '<a href="{url}"><span>{label}</span></a>']
    ]
]);
```

I need to receive:

```
<li class="tab"><a href="/v2/finish-by-code"><span>Finish</span></a></li>
```

But receive:

```
<li class="tab"><a href="/v2/finish-by-code">Finish</a></li>
```

Without **span**

Comment: looking  to doc .. i don't sees a template entry for items  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#$items-detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need  html inside label  you could use label and encode => false

```
echo \yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class'=>'top_choice'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => '<span>Finish</span>',  'options' => ['class' => 'tab'], 
                   'url' => ['/finish'],]
    ],
    'encodeLabels' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo \yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
 'encodeLabels' => false,
 'options' => ['class'=>'top_choice'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => '<span>Finish</span>',  'options' => ['class' => 'tab'], 'url' => ['/finish']]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps!